# How do I handle Security between two Grails apps?

Tags: grails

If I have two separate Grails apps running on the same app server (Tomcat/Glassfish), how do I allow the user to log into the first app then have him authenticated for the second app so he's not prompted when he goes to that app?

Comment: How does the person 'go' to the second app? By a link from the first app? by launching another browser session and typing in the url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO the best way to go for it is to implement a federated login server. For example [CAS](http://www.ja-sig.org/products/cas/) (Central Authentication Service) which is a Web Single Sign-On solution. This would also allow to integrate application running on different app servers/machines.

Answer (score 0):

there is a crowd plugin for grails that enables crowd integration - see http://www.atlassian.com/software/crowd/ for details.

Answer (score 0):

I'd also suggest going the CAS route. The newest acegi plugin has CAS support which should make it pretty easy. But with CAS you still need authorization (what the user can do) as its purpose is authentication (who the user is).